# RTTI SetValue вызывает Access Violation при использовании пакетной/плагинной архитектуры приложения

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Имеется приложение, состоящее из главного модуля, подключаемых плагинов, реализованных в виде `bpl` и связующего звена `PluginInterface`. В плагинах есть куча структур, точнее классов. Требуется поименовать все поля в данных структурах. Для проверки того, что задача решаема, я написал простенькое приложение:

```
program TypeCast;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.RTTI, Generics.Collections;

type
  TSpr = class
  public
    s: string;
    i: Integer;
    b: Boolean;
  end;

var
  Spr: TSpr;
  vCtx: TRTTIContext;
  vType: TRTTIType;
  vField: TRTTIField;
  Dict: TDictionary<string, TRTTIField>;

begin
  try
    Spr := TSpr.Create;
    vType := vCtx.GetType(TSpr.ClassInfo);
    Dict := TDictionary<string, TRTTIField>.Create;
    for vField in vType.GetFields do
      Dict.AddOrSetValue(vField.Name, vField);
    Dict['s'].SetValue(Spr, 'Hello World!');
    Dict['i'].SetValue(Spr, 123);
    Dict['b'].SetValue(Spr, True);
    Writeln(Spr.s);
    Writeln(Spr.i);
    Writeln(Spr.b);
    Spr.Free;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> Hello World!
> 123
> TRUE
> ```

Работает она в таком виде без проблем. Но когда я начинаю использовать данную технику в уже написанных пакетах, начинается какой-то, не побоюсь этого слова, полтергейст.

**MCVE / Чтобы воспроизвести:**
<sup>*...предполагается, что изначально среда пуста...*</sup>

1. Пакет `PluginInterface` выглядит вот так. Здесь есть `UClassManager`

   ```
   unit UClassManager;

   interface

   uses
     Classes, Contnrs;

   type
     TClassManager = class(TClassList);

   function ClassManager: TClassManager;

   implementation

   var
     Manager: TClassManager;

   function ClassManager: TClassManager;
   begin
     Result := Manager;
   end;

   initialization
   Manager := TClassManager.Create;

   finalization
   Manager.Free;

   end.
   ```

   ...и `UPlugin`.

   ```
   unit UPlugin;

   interface

   uses RTTI;

   type
     TPlugin = class
     public
       procedure Init; virtual; abstract;
       function SetProp(Key: string; Value: TValue): Boolean; virtual; abstract;
     end;

     TPluginClass = class of TPlugin;
     IPluginHost = interface
       function RunPlugin(PluginName: string): TPlugin; // Run Plugin by it's ClassName
     end;

   var
     Host: IPluginHost;

   implementation

   end.
   ```
2. Создайте `VCL Forms Application`, включите поддержку рантайм-пакетов, добавьте `PluginInterface` в его зависимости и положите на форму кнопку. На соответствующие события повесьте вот такие обработчики:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     LoadPackage('UniversalSpr.bpl');
     Host := Self;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   var
     Plugin: TPlugin;
   begin
     Plugin := Host.RunPlugin('TSprPlugin');
     Plugin.Init;
     Plugin.SetProp('SprTableName', 'MATERIALS');
     Plugin.SetProp('EditRights', True);
     Plugin.SetProp('BeforePostValue1', 3);
   end;

   function TForm1.RunPlugin(PluginName: string): TPlugin;
   var
     I: Integer;
   begin
     Result := nil;
     for I := 0 to ClassManager.Count - 1 do
       if ClassManager[I].ClassNameIs(PluginName) then begin
         Result := TPluginClass(ClassManager[I]).Create;
         Break;
       end;
   end;
   ```

   Естественно, `TForm1` должна унаследовать функционал `IPluginHost`. `UClassManager` и `UPlugin` должны быть указаны в предложении `uses`. Другие необходимые юниты оболочка добавит сама.
3. Сделайте пакет `UniversalSpr` и настройте его так, чтобы выходной файл компиляции попадал в тот же самый каталог, что и приложение-хост. Сделайте плагин `TSprPlugin`, унаследовав его от `TPlugin`:

   ```
   unit USprPlugin;

   interface

   uses
     UPlugin, RTTI, Generics.Collections;

   type
     TSpr = class
       SprTableName: string;
       BeforePostValue1: int64;
       EditRights: boolean;
     end;
     TSprPlugin = class(TPlugin)
       procedure Init; override;
       function SetProp(Key: string; Value: TValue): Boolean; override;
       private
         Spr: TSpr;
         PropDict: TDictionary<string, TRTTIField>;
     end;

   implementation

   procedure TSprPlugin.Init;
   var
     vCtx: TRTTIContext;
     vType: TRTTIType;
     vField: TRTTIField;
   begin
     if not Assigned(Spr) then
       Spr := TSpr.Create;
     vType := vCtx.GetType(Spr.ClassInfo);
     if not Assigned(PropDict) then
       PropDict := TDictionary<string, TRTTIField>.Create;
     for vField in vType.GetFields do
       PropDict.Add(vField.Name, vField);
   end;

   function TSprPlugin.SetProp(Key: string; Value: TValue): Boolean;
   var
     Field: TRTTIField;
   begin
     Result := PropDict.TryGetValue(Key, Field);
     if Result then
       // тут происходит нарушение доступа
       Field.SetValue(Spr, Value);
   end;

   end.
   ```

После нажатия кнопки на форме, вы сможете вызвать сеттер/мутатор объявленных свойств, но попытка повторить трюк с тайпкастом внутри нашего сеттера приведёт к Access Violation при доступе к `00000004`.

Длительное расследование и партизанский допрос отладчика помогли выяснить, что в сеттере `Field.FieldType` вычисляется корректно, и это объясняет, почему не выбрасывается исключение `InsufficientRTTI`, однако, попытка обращения к `Field.FieldType.Handle` вызывает нашу ошибку доступа. Хендл вызывается внутри метода `SetValue`, и его в принципе можно убрать, что я и сделал:

```
function TSprPlugin.SetProp(Key: string; Value: TValue): Boolean;
var
  Field: TRTTIField;
begin
  Result := PropDict.TryGetValue(Key, Field);
  if Result then
    Value.ExtractRawData(PByte(Spr) + Field.Offset);
end;
```

Однако, тогда не будет вызываться преобразование типа, что довольно опасно в случае, если кто-то другой решит воспользоваться плодами моих трудов. На английском SO мне рекомендовали отказаться от использования пакетов, но это не представляется реальным. Возможно ли решить ошибку с получением хендла, *не отказываясь от использования пакетов*?

P.S. Прошу не критиковать за утечки памяти, в исходном приложении имеются все нужные методы для её освобождения. Я лишь привёл необходимый код для воспроизведения проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может то что я напишу не совсем ответ, а результат моих наблюдений, но я думаю это может пригодится...

Недавно я писал скрипт для "иды про", который мог анализировать rtti в исполняемых файлах. Входе разработки я просматривал исходники модуля RTTI и параллельно анализировал, как данные располагаются в бинарнике.

И вот, что я смог почерпнуть из моего анализа:

1) Самое главное!!! Большинство внутренних форматов rtti описаны в typinfo.pas, но это не дает полной информации. То есть в структуре типа могут быть подводные камни, которые можно узнать только анализируя исходники rtti.pas и то как эта информация хранится в бинарнике.

2) Возможно rtti в .exe и в .bpl может отличаться. Это я выяснял, когда попытался прогнать свой скрипт на .bpl. В .exe скрипт отрабатывал нормально, а в .bpl весь анализ запарывался(если мне не изменяет память, то анализ ломался на какой то структуре).

3) Если работаешь с rtti в .bpl, то нет гарантий, что сможешь получить всю информацию о типе или что все будет работать без исключений. Это вывод я сделал после написания небольшого кода(код использовал rtti.pas), который анализировал rtti в самой delphi(код подключался как плагин к delphi). В ходе работы этого кода периодически случались очень редкие исключения на определенных типах в недрах модуля rtti.pas.

Вывод из этого такой: Внутреняя структура rtti сложна и разработчики могли банально ошибится в rtti.pas. Вашу проблему может и можно решить, но вам придется хорошо покопаться, чтобы выяснить в чем ошибка, а потом еще придется как то исправить ошибку.

**PS:** Так как инфа по rtti не документируется в полном в виде, то я вполне могу ошибаться по поводу пунктов 2.

Comment: Фактически судя по документации, все public поля следует сделать published и тогда RTTI заработает. Я сделал немного по-другому, вообще отказался от RTTI и в принципе оказалось, что так даже лучше. Однако, RTTI мне всё равно пригодилось и продолжает пригождаться. Оно позволяет использовать кое-где более изящные решения.